# QImage invalid when path with umlauts

Tags: opencv, path

I am reading in an image (opencv) , editing it and want to save it to a QImage to display it in a Qt widget. This works also. But only if there are no umlauts in the path. As soon as there are umlauts in the path, no image is displayed.
For testing I always took the same image and only changed the path name (inserted an ä)

```
...
cv::Mat imageCV = cv::imread(info.absoluteFilePath().toStdString(), cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH | cv::IMREAD_COLOR); 

 ... // do some stuff....

QImage displayImage = QImage((const uchar*) imageCV.data, imageCV.cols, imageCV.rows, imageCV.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

When I debug through the code it just shows me "invalid" for displayImage. no other info.
When I step over the last line of code.

Is the path somehow passed in a wrong format ?

--- UPDATE ---
my mistake i just saw the imread is the problem, not the last code line.

i search for answers

Comment: i only find python requests, no c++.

Comment: `cv::imread` doesn't support unicode AFAIK. I'd personally avoid anything but pure ASCII for filenames, but feel free to experiment with what works.

Comment: Perhaps you could load the contents of the file into memory using standard file IO (which should be more flexible), and use `cv::imdecode` on the loaded buffer.